# Can a PandasUDF take in a series of type String and return a series of type Array?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use PandasUDF's to preprocess images. This involves converting from Base64 strings to NumPy arrays. I would like the PandasUDF to take in a series of type string, and return a series of type list (I can convert np array to list before putting it into a Pandas series). Using the following code, I get the error `pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object`

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

    @pandas_udf("string", ArrayType(IntegerType()))
    def base64_to_np(base64_images: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
        for images in base64_images:
            img_arrays = []
            for img in list(images):
                img_bytes = base64.b64decode(img)
                img_array = np.load(BytesIO(img_bytes))
                img_arrays.append(img_array.tolist()) # img_arrays.append(str(img_array)) works
            img_series = pd.Series(img_arrays, copy = False)
            yield img_series
```

However, I am able to run this UDF if I return the np array after casting it into a string. It would be better if I could return a series of type array so I won't have to convert from string to array later on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question and I would like to know the answer as well
BTW How would you cast from string to array later? I am curious...

Comment: You can cast from string to array like so, using the help of the ast library: `arr = np.array(ast.literal_eval(str))`